# Drupal 6 primary links: how do I link to my latest news?

Tags: drupal-6, hyperlink, menuitem

I've defined a custom content type - news. I also have a menu item - latest news - that links to one of the news nodes. I want it to link to the latest of them. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Common end user approach:** Using the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views), you create a view page (with its own path) that only shows the latest (or n latest) node(s). Then you point your menu item to that page.

---

**Alternate developer approach:** If you want to avoid the overhead of the views module, you could also implement [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6) within a custom module. There you'd register a custom callback function for a new path (e.g. '/show/latest/news'). The callback function would then determine the latest news node and either render it itself, or redirect to its path using [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_goto/6). Your menu item would point to the new path.